# Custom adapter with fragmet in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, custom-adapter

i want to create a custom listview in fragment not in listFragment because i use
FragmentPagerAdapter

```
public class ListCategorie  extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public ListCategorie(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

       Fragment frag=null;
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                frag=new Fragment_plats();
                break;
            case 1:
                frag=new Fragment_dessert();
                break;
            case 2:
                frag=new Fragment_gateaux();
                break;
        }
        return frag;
    }


}
```

any help please ?.
thank you .

Comment: Add ListView in Fragment xml layout in which u want. is there any issue?

Comment: the prob is when  use listview you must use ListFragment but i want use it in fragment